Is exposing Authority, ClientID and Scope through unprotected endpoint secure?
Recently I found an unprotected endpoint in BFF API that exposes:

ClientId
Scope
Authority

Frontend consuming this endpoint uses this response to kick off AuthorizationCode + PKCE flow.
Is this secure?

Yes - anyone who can access the home page of a secured web app and trigger a code flow, eg by clicking a login button, can see that information in the authorization request:
GET /oauth/v2/authorize
Host: login.example.com
 
client_id=my-client&
redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/callback&
response_type=code&
scope=openid profile&
code_challenge=WhmRaP18B9z2zkYcIlb4uVcZzjLqcZsaBQJf5akUxsA&
code_challenge_method=S256&
state=CfDJ8Nxa-YhPzjpBilDQz2C...

Personally I prefer a BFF to create runtime authorization request URLs for the frontend as follows. The values you mention are still exposed to anyone who triggers the login though.
POST /login/start
Host: bff.myapp.com

